# Click desktop icon and doc item From transparent borderless window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode5

I have a borderless and transparent (alpha value is .5) NSwindow as shown in the image below. Now i have to click doc and desktop item from this window 
i researched on google and can't find related to it

Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this.

below code is for creating NSWindow [image].

```
NSRect screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen]frame];

captureItFullWindow = [[CapTureFullWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO ];

[captureItFullWindow setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel];

[captureItFullWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

[captureItFullWindow setOpaque:NO];  //Tells the window manager that the window might have transparent parts.
[captureItFullWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3]];
```

Comment: Have a look at CGEventPostToPSN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its too easy when i got the answer

only i have to set window mouse ignoring property

```
[self setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
```